# Задача на логику элементов

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть 4 элемента. Мне нужно их как то различать, чтобы потом сравнивать и рассчитывать что больше. К примеру I1 > I2 и так далее. Всего есть 4 элемента: 0,1,2,3. Как мне не создавать путаницу и при этом я смог бы рассчитать что больше через оператор if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно - не понял вопроса. Если у вас есть какие то числовые эквиваленты элементам (как то вы их будете сравнивать?), то вы изначально будете знать что больше. С чем сравнивать будете? Три земли больше двух огней и одного воздуха? Если так, то Enum вам в помощь:

```
    private enum Element
    {
      earth=70,
      air=35,
      water=48,
      fire=63
    }
....
if((int)Element.earth*3>(int)Element.fire*2 + (int)Element.air))
{
do...
}
```

Если значимый тип вам не подходит, то делайте классы.
Или переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: У меня есть 4 элемента и мне нужно их сравнить, но при этом есть одно правило (Воздух>дерево>дерево>вода>огонь). А теперь мне нужно в коде сделать также через if

Comment: ну и сделайте через enum и сравнивайте их значения. В чем проблема то? Ну или создайте структуру, переопределите "==" и сравнивайте экземпляры, или создайте массив (строковый) и сравнивайте индексы массива. В общем вариантов куча.

Comment: (int)Element.earth>(int)Element.fire

Comment: Вариантов куча, но у юнити есть свои идиотские особенности. Например я не могу запустить public static rr bool[]; только потому что rr содержит массив, как и через синглтон. В любом случае спасибо за помощь, придется все таки без массива делать. Не люблю куски кода.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь не идет о обработке каждый кадр, можно использовать сортировку 
 [order by](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.3.php)

Если Enum

```
enum Element
    {   Fire =1,
        Water =2,
        Earth =3,
        Air =4
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Element>();
        list.Add(Element.Air);
        list.Add(Element.Earth);
        list.Add(Element.Fire);
        list.Add(Element.Air);
    foreach(var element in list)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(element);
    }

    System.Console.WriteLine();

    list.Sort();

    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

отсортируется по значением в enum.

Если реализуешь элементы через классы, будет работать так же, если реализуешь [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Вариант отличный, только к юнити не подойдет. К сожалению есть некие трудности. К примеру, у меня есть 4 элемента(воздух, огонь, вода, дерево) и мне нужно каким то образом различать их, чтобы потом через if работала моя часть кода

Comment: Элементы определены через Enum?

Comment: В виде int)пока только до этого додумался

Comment: if (SelectItemsP1[1] > SelectItemsP2[0])
            {
            }
            if (SelectItemsP1[2] > SelectItemsP2[0])
            {
            }
            if (SelectItemsP1[3] > SelectItemsP2[0])
            {          
            } 
что нибудь подобное. проблема в том, что в итоге обрабатываются несколько if

Comment: if (SelectItemsP1[1] > SelectItemsP2[0]) { } ....Если это так, есть смысл обернуть элементы в классы.

Comment: фактически они у меня обернуты. каким образом мне их сравнить?